# Is it correct to use "git" as verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, meaning-in-context, terminology

I know that the word *git* is used for describing an unpleasant person.
Also *Git* is a name of a version control system which is quite popular among software developers.

I thought this word did not form verbs. But recently I found a use *git* as verb in a phrase which was written by a native speaker from US, on the Heroku blog. In "[10 Habits of a Happy Node Hacker (2016)](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/11/10/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits)," #9 is

> **9. Only git the important bits**
> Most apps are composed of both necessary files and generated files. When using a source control system like git, you should avoid tracking anything that's generated.
>
> For example, your node app probably has a `node_modules` directory for dependencies, which you should keep out of git. As long as each dependency is listed in package.json, anyone can create a working local copy of your app - including `node_modules` - by running `npm install`.

Is it correct to use *to git* in meaning "to use the computer program Git" like *to google* means "to search something in Google"?

Or maybe it's wordplay based on the homophony of *git* and *get*?

Comment: You have to ask the person I think. Can you please fix some typos in your question?

Comment: @choster Thank you! I found the phrase as a caption of a paragraph in computer article: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/11/10/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits

Comment: In deep southern and Appalachian mountain American dialects, "git" is the pronunciation of "get".

Comment: @pinocchio964 Thanks; I have edited your post to include the context, and in my opinion the question is now answerable.

Comment: [necromancer's comment] Consider the sentence: "Captains man ships in the harbour". One of the beauties of English (which often puzzles non-natives) is the freedom it gives in using a noun where a verb is normally used. Which does not mean, of course, that you can do this with any noun in any sentence, you need to think and ask yourself - will other people understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite common to use the name of a computer program as a verb, but it would be considered "[jargon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jargon)" which is specialized, work-related slang and terminology only used and understood by a niche subset of people with a common job (or hobby).  Like most slang, it isn't typically used in formal communication (although there can be exceptions).

The pattern of "[verbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28word_formation%29#Verbification)" the name of a computer program is especially common for Linux/Unix-based programs such as *git* (probably because they are typically *functional*; they perform a specific action).

This usage would be understood by most programmers, at least those who work with *git*, and baffle most people outside of the field.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer depends on the crowd you call company at the time you decide to verb GIT. If your audience is all computer science types, GIT'n it may not be a problem, also true if your audience is all from the backwoods south, Git'r done. In polite society however, if you refer to Giting something, you may have more then chagrin to worry about.